# C++ Zooming Graphical Content

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm trying to make a program that handles graphics and I am not quite sure how to implement zooming. I have done a zooming effect with primitive shapes such as lines and circles (with SDL_gfxPrimitives) by scaling them down but that wont work for a picture. How would I implement zooming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a SDL library that supports zooming:

[SDL2_gfx Library](http://www.ferzkopp.net/joomla/content/view/19/14/)

> The SDL_gfx library evolved out of the SDL_gfxPrimitives code which
>   provided basic drawing routines such as lines, circles or polygons and
>   SDL_rotozoom which implemented a interpolating rotozoomer for SDL
>   surfaces.
>
> > The current components of the SDL_gfx library are:
> >
> > - Graphic Primitives (SDL_gfxPrimitves.h)
> > - Rotozoomer (SDL_rotozoom.h)
> > - Framerate control (SDL_framerate.h)
> > - MMX image filters (SDL_imageFilter.h)
> > - Custom Blit functions (SDL_gfxBlitFunc.h)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not specific enough to produce a specific answer that is likely to get you what you appear to be looking for.

What I can offer you is the suggestion that you first come up with a way to **represent** zooming.

If you already know how to **draw** a picture, consider the fact that when it comes to computer graphics, it is almost always the case that "zooming in" or "zooming out" is nothing more than drawing your picture at a progressively larger or smaller size.

With that in mind, maybe you will begin to see that a reasonable way to represent the concept of zooming is with some form of `Camera` class that will unambiguously determine the size and location of the pictures you draw.

Comment: i was about to just say that. but yea just increase the size of the canvas your putting the texture on

Comment: I'm pretty sure that with most graphics systems, modifying the output texture size will not magically "zoom" your drawing.

Comment: so if i lets say have a RECT the size of the screen and draw the texture onto that RECT. now if i double the RECT size its not gonna make it look like its zoomed in? i can tell you it does .....
also i never said texture size canvas you know the thing your drawing your texture on?

Comment: I am talking about zooming an image like a photo